# Refreshing token with on-behalf-of flow (single-sign-on with Teams)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a single-sign-on scenario with Microsoft Teams. See full description in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso

I am getting an access token by "trading" the "teams" token for an access token.

My question is, **how do I refresh this access token**? In single-sign-on scenario the "refrehs_token" is not returned (?), so normal OAuth2 refresh flow does not seem to be possible.

Imagine I traded it once, and got the access token that expires in say 2 hours. I use it to access graph API (or whatever), and then the token expires.

What should I do to get a new access token? Can I just ask Teams for a fresh "teams" token and trade it again in case the old one expired? Teams App takes care of refreshing its own tokens, right? When should I do this (when I get "access denied", or just if I see that the token has expired?

Comment: Are you using [C# sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp)?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#refreshing-tokens.

Comment: In our app, we just check if the token has expired. If yes, we exchange it again.

Comment: Thanks, followed withe the link - the issue I was not getting the refresh_token turned out to be easier though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the reason - you **must** pass `offline_access` as scope request then you get back the `refresh_token`. That was my issue actually, and it is documented, I just did not read carefully:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

> **refresh_token** The refresh token for the requested access token. The calling service can use this token to request another access token after the current access token expires. The refresh token is only provided if the **offline_access** scope was requested.